# 401k tax breaks - what is the gain?

Tags: united-states, taxes

There are many countries that do not tax money put away for retirement - such as into a 401K. Why does this make sense?
It is smart to save for retirement, but what does the govornment gain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The US does not put money into 401K programs. What the US government does do with 401K programs is to provide deferred taxation on money that goes into those programs (traditional IRAs) or tax-free growth in the case of a Roth IRA. In a sense, that is a subsidy. In another sense, it is anything but a subsidy. The taxes are collected later on traditional IRAs.

The Internal Revenue Service places strict limits regarding how much people can invest in those programs. The goal is to get people in the lower and middle classes to save for their retirement so as to augment the pauper level benefits from Social Security. Those in the upper classes need to invest in non-401K devices to maintain their upper class lifestyle in retirement.

Note that having one million dollars in an IRA on retirement means $40,000 per year (inflation adjusted) per the 4% rule. That's enough to nicely augment those pauper level Social Security benefits, but it is not anywhere close to the level of a wealthy living. Being the millionaire next door does not mean what it used to mean.

Note also that 401K programs go into traditional IRAs rather than Roth IRAs. Both the principal and investment gains are taxed upon withdrawal from a 401K. In a sense, 401K programs are a mechanism by which the US government can indirectly invest in stock markets. (The US government is forbidden by law from directly investing in stock markets.) Since the stock market outperforms bonds in the long term, 401K programs are a long term net winner for the US government.

Comment: What do employers gain by matching funds put into a 401K account?

Comment: @Burt The same things they gain by offering other supplemental benefits. Employees in certain career fields expect a certain level of non-cash benefits, such a medical insurance and the like. If an employer doesn't offer these benefits, another one typically will and will out-compete for talent.

Not all employers offer these benefits, for things like contracted work, but the cash compensation is typically adjusted to make up for such loss of benefits.

Comment: @Drise Yep. A checklist I have used included: Does this prospective employer do interesting things? Is that interesting work likely to continue? Do they pay well? Do they provide good benefits (insurance, 401K, paid time off, other stuff)? Do they have a good company culture? Is the leadership sane? Are their employees sane? Do they expect me to work an insane number of hours, week-in, week-out? A no on any of those (except the last one) means try the next prospective employer. Interviews are a two-way street.

Comment: Essentially deferred taxation has two advantages for the taxpayer, the first is it allows them to defer the income until a time when they are probablly in a lower tax bracker. The second and far more important effect is the way it interacts with compounding of interest/profits.

Comment: The repeated _pauper level_ description of Social Security benefits seems exaggerated.  As members of the comfortable middle class, monthly benefits listed on our Social Security statements exceeds current monthly outlays, exclusive of post-secondary education.  (Yes, I'm well aware that future payments may not match current statement projections, but that's a subject apart from whether this is _pauper level_ income.)

Comment: @user4556274 The average monthly Social Security check for a retired person was [$1,676.53 as of October 2022](https://www.bankrate.com/retirement/average-monthly-social-security-check/). That's $20118.36 per year. While not quite poverty level (poverty level for a household of 2 is $19,720 per year), it's close, and that this is average (not median) also means a lot of people are receiving even less than that when they retire -- and that is poverty level.

Comment: The average (and the median) include those who work at least 10 years to qualify for minimal retirement benefits, but less than 35, and more importantly, the large majority that choose early retirement in exchange for reduced monthly benefits.  The most common retirement age is 62, corresponding to a ~40% reduction in monthly benefits (varying depending on lifetime income level), with about [2/3 retiring with _some_ reduction](https://bipartisanpolicy.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/BPC-Economy-Brief-SS-Claiming.pdf).

Comment: @user4556274 The document to which you linked was very careful to distinguish between "median" and "average". Given a skewed statistic (income is a very skewed statistic), the average (mean) is typically higher than the median.

Comment: @user4556274 Also note that the document to which you linked reported a sub-poverty level "average", but that's mostly because that document included disability benefits and survivor benefits in its average. A lifetime long low income but above poverty level earner will see poverty level Social Security benefits. A lifetime long median income level earner while working will see pauper level Social Security benefits. A high income earner will see about $50k per year, which is not bad, but to those high income earners that is pauper level. The only solution is to save on ones own.

Answer (score 9):

Economically it makes sense to encourage saving for a pension, as those who don't save will have to be supported entirely from taxation.

Retired people can't work to get money, so they are dependent on their savings or the government.  By encouraging saving in a pension, the government hopes to save money in state pensions.

Comment: To be more precise - the government wants to encourage investments into productive ventures via pension funds. It also helps reduce inflation and thus unlock more leeway for government spending. At the end of the day money is an imaginary concept of zero value - what we really want is future goods and services, which can be improved by making investments today.